# Test for significance before testing

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, control-group, treatment

I got a question regarding the binomial distribution and testing for significance in general.

I need to divide a dataset into a treatment group (with phone call) and a control group (no phone call). My boss told me I need to divide it based on significance tests. However, I told him that's not possible if no one has been called yet, since I have no data to work with now (what is the success rate? what is the number of successes?).

The question is: First, am I wrong for thinking that this request with the signficance tests is not possible? Second, how would I divide the control and treatment group in a logical way? I was thinking about 90/10 since I have a limited sample size, but I have no way of supporting my choice other than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your boss is saying that when you define your control and test groups through a random assignment, you should test that there are no existing significant differences between the 2 groups prior to intervention. If there were, then the post-intervention analysis would be skewed.

Comment: Thanks! Since my data is heavily skewed to the right do I need to transform it first by exponentiation (I then get a uniform distribution) and then test for no significant differences?

Comment: No need to transform here, as the Binomial test is _exact_.

Comment: @StephenTheunissen: If you found the answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept.